# Rem based gutters without Calc()

Tags: css, sass

I am building a grid system and I am pretty happy with what I have so far. The major problem I have is getting the gutters to calculate properly. I want to have split margins (margin on each side of column and negative margins on the row). But I cannot figure out the best approach here or the math for that matter. I want rem based margins without using the calc() function in sass.

Is this doable?

If someone could point me in the right direction, or have a link that would helpful It would be appreciated.

### Sassmeister Link

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/31ad1059e96fb709f8463c85be5a042f

```
// ----
// Sass (v3.5.6)
// Compass (vundefined)
// ----

//Variable Declarations
$__grid--columns:12;
$__grid--breakpoints: (
    'xxxsmall': 375px,
    'xxsmall':  480px,
    'xsmall':   667px,
    'small':    768px,
    'medium':   960px,
    'large':    1024px,
    'xlarge':   1200px,
    'xxlarge':  1400px,
    'xxxlarge': 1600px,
);
$__grid--gutters: (
    'small':    30px,
    'medium':   30px,
    'large':    30px
);
$__grid--cell-containers: (
    'small':    1200px,
    'medium':   1400px,
    'large':    1600px,
    'full':     100%
);






$font-size: 16px;
@function rem($size) {
    $remSize:$size / $font-size;
    @return #{$remSize}rem;
}


//Mixins for Grid
@mixin createGutters() {
  @each $key, $value in $__grid--gutters {
    //Media Query Mixin{

    // }
  }
}
@mixin createCells() {
  @each $key, $value in $__grid--breakpoints {
    @media screen and (min-width:$value){
      @for $i from 1 through $__grid--columns {
        &.#{$key}-#{$i}{
          //gutterFunction();
          flex-basis:(100 / ($__grid--columns / $i) * 1%);
          //Offset
          margin-left:(100 / ($__grid--columns / $i) * 1%);
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
.container {
    position:relative;
}
//Spit out the cells
.row,
.column{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;

}

.column {
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
.row {
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.cell {
  background-color:blue;
  @include createCells;
}








//Styles not needed for grid
// * {
//   box-sizing:border-box;
// }
// .color {
//   padding:10px;
//   background-color:salmon;
// }
















// @mixin create-mq($breakpoint) {
//   @if($breakpoint == 0) {
//     @content;
//   } @else {
//     @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint *1px) {
//       @content;
//     }
//   }
// }

// @mixin create-col-classes($modifier, $grid-cols, $breakpoint) {
//   @include create-mq($breakpoint) {
//     &__col#{$modifier}-offset-0 {
//       margin-left: 0;
//     }
//     @for $i from 1 through $grid-cols {
//       &__col#{$modifier}-#{$i} {
//         flex-basis: (100 / ($grid-cols / $i) ) * 1rem;
//       }
//       &__col#{$modifier}-offset-#{$i} {
//         margin-left: (100 / ($grid-cols / $i) ) * 1rem;
//       }
//     }
//   }
// }

// .container {
//   max-width: $grid__bp-md * 1px;
//   margin: 0 auto;
//   &--fluid {
//     margin: 0;
//     max-width: 100%;
//   }
//   &__row {
//     display: flex;
//     flex-wrap: wrap;
//     width: 100%;
//   }
//   @each $modifier , $breakpoint in $map-grid-props {
//     @include create-col-classes($modifier, $grid__cols, $breakpoint);
//   }
// }

// //Styling of grid for demostration purposes
// .container {
//   background-color: #88d8b0;
//   padding: 10px;
//   box-sizing: border-box;
//   &__row {
//     background-color: #ffeead;
//     &.nested {
//       background-color: #ffcc5c;
//     }
//   }

//   @at-root {
//     [class*='container__col-'] {
//       &.higher {
//         min-height: 60px;
//       }
//       min-height: 30px;
//       background-color: #ff6f69;
//       outline: 1px solid #ffcc5c;
//       display: flex;
//       align-items: center;
//       justify-content: space-around;
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Just trying to get a clearer picture. Why do you have left margin on the cells? Should the end result be a row with negative left and right margins of 1/2 gutter, cells have left and right margins of 1/2 gutter, and cell width is the percent you've calculated minus the gutter?

Comment: @JasonB Whoops. That left margin should be there. Forgot to remove. You are correct. It should be a split left and right margin. I just don’t want to use calc in this instance. Any ideas?

Comment: So you are trying to combine units, percentage and rem, without using calc?

Comment: @JasonB It doesn’t have to be a combination of units in the end. I just know I want rem based margins, paddings, etc in the end. If it can all be done in rems fine. The main thing is paddings and margins need to be rems here. Maybe the calculation needs to change?